# Fundamental Group of Infinite Wedge

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I can apply van-kampen's theorem finitely many times to compute the fundamental group of finite wedge of circles.
But when I am supposed to compute the fundamental group of infinite wedge of circles, then how can I do that?

What I am trying to emphasize is that I can apply van-kampen's theorem and find the fundamental group after a finite number of steps but that isn't possible when the number of circles is infinite. Then what can I do in this case?
How do I convince myself?

Morever many answers has directly used that the fundamental group of infinite wedge of circles is free product but how exactly I convince myself

Comment: You can use this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1880596/direct-limit-of-fundamental-homotopy-groups-of-an-increasing-sequence-of-topolog

Comment: Read the account of van Kampen theorem in Hatcher or Massey and find that it directly deals with the case of infinite unions.